# how to switch between input type="text" and textarea using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, text, input, textarea

please help me on this code or another working code that switch between input type="text" and textarea using jquery.

```
$(function(){
$("a#change").toggle(function(){
  var input = document.getElementById('text'),
  textarea  = document.createElement('textarea');
  textarea.id    = input.id;
  textarea.cols  = 40;
  textarea.rows  = 5;
  textarea.value = input.value;
  input.parentNode.replaceChild(textarea,input);
  return false;
},function(){
  textarea.parentNode.replaceChild(input,textarea);
  return false;
});
```

});

```
<input type="text" name="text" id="text" /><a href="#" id="change">change</a>
```

Comment: Can you show us the HTML? You probably need to detect at which Node-number the `textarea` is and then replace that node index with the `input` field. They're different types of elements, so you need to catch data you want to transfer and then rewrite the elements position with a new element.

Comment: your second function is trying to access an undefined `textarea` variable.

Comment: possible copy of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2382289/changing-input-text-to-textarea-just-like-in-facebook

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? Using [`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/) in this manner is no longer valid (depreciated version 1.8, removed version 1.9).

Comment: <input type="text" name="text" id="text" />
<a href="#" id="change">change</a>

Comment: I would suggest putting the `<input>` and `<textarea>` in original markup and just toggling their visibility and `disabled` property (and _id_ if id's are necessary in your context). This will avoid DOM add/remove manipulation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following should work for you.

```
var textbox = $("#textbox");
var textarea = $("<textarea id='textarea'></textarea>");
$("#change").click(function () {
    //Check for textbox or textarea
    if ($("#textbox").length === 1) {
        //Copy value to textarea
        textarea.val(textbox.val());
        //Replace textbox with textarea
        textbox = textbox.replaceWith(textarea);
    } else {
        //Copy value to textbox
        textbox.val(textarea.val());
        //Replace textarea with textbox
        textarea = textarea.replaceWith(textbox);
    }
});
```

You can set the cols and rows in line two in you need to.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Dracs/WzE48/2/)